# get errors at Color in vs express 2012

Tags: c#

i'm trying to change button color with other button click.

`button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(100,100,100));`

i get error at Color.

and i'm using microsoft visual studio express 2012 for windows8.

i tried color name and color code. Don't understand this solidColorbrush thing.

thanks!

Comment: Well i see only [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.fromargb.aspx), i guess you are using a method name which does not exist

Answer (score 2):

I guess the error is

> Color does not contain a definition for **FromRgb**

The method for your case would be [Color.FromArgb,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.fromargb.aspx)

If not the case please update the question with relevant error message

```
button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100));
```